# Change the backgroundcolor of Touchable / Pressable Item after pressing

Tags: react-native, onpress

I'm currently working on an app prototype with **react native**. There's a lot out there on how to change the color of a component, here **Touchable** or **Pressable**, when pressing it (=> **onPress**).
But how do i change the backgroundcolor of such a component permanently after clicking – with **onPressOut?**.
Example:

simple "Click me" component that has a green background by default. If clicked once, it should change to a red background. Clicked once again, it should go back to green (and so on).

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to control it using the `state` of component.

I did a live demo for you:

https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-sea-5331l?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

const App = props => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={{ width: "30%", alignItems: "center", marginTop: 20 }}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => setSelected(!selected)}
        style={{ backgroundColor: selected ? "red" : "transparent" }}
      >
        Press me
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3):

2023 Way:

```
import { Pressable, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native'

const App = props => {
    return (
        <Pressable
          onPress={() => someFunction()}
          style={({ pressed }) => [
              { backgroundColor: pressed ? 'red' : 'transparent' },
              styles.otherStyles
          ]}
      >
        <Text>Press Me</Text>
      </Pressable>
   )

}
```

credit: https://medium.com/timeless/a-simple-touch-feedback-with-the-new-pressable-component-b4d91c35456

Comment: Loved the simplicity of this way. Thank you. Works like a charm.